# Heroku Youtube-dl page

Tags: python, heroku, youtube-dl

Hey everybody current i am busy developing a app that needs to retrieve a youtube url. Now i know youtube-dl is written in .py and is the best tool for this. `youtube-dl --get-url YOUTUBE_URL` retrieves the video url for me as i expect it to.

Is it possible for me to somehow bridge a .py webpage to this python script and echoes the output for me into a webpage that is hosted on heroku?

I have however managed to get this to work in PHP but my webhost simply does not allow the execution of scripts in php so it is rendered useless. The script that i have is as following.

```
    <?php

function serveFile( $file ){

    $output = '';
    $prep = `cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/youtube-dl`;
    $fp = popen('./youtube-dl --get-url '.$file.' 2>&1', "r");

    while(!feof($fp)){
        $myLine = fread($fp, 1024);
        $buffer = $myLine;
        //echo $myLine;
        $output .= trim($buffer);
    }
    fclose($fp);
    return $output;
}

$video_url =  serveFile("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$_GET['v']);

echo json_encode(
    array("url" => $video_url)
)
//echo $video_url;
?>
```

I am extreamly new to python and heroku so please be nice to me :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm running dwnYT.com. There is plenty of libraries for downloading youtube videos. On heroku I was trying libraries for node.js and e.g. node-ytdl-core was going without problem. 
Also You can use some APIs that gives you link without any programing.